# Save SQL print text into SSIS variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I want to know if is possible save a PRINT SQL text into SSIS variable.

My query is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE month = '1' or month = '2' or month = '3' or month = '4' 
            or month = '5' or month = '6' or month = '7' or month = '8' or month = '9')
BEGIN
PRINT = 'EXIST' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT = 'NOT_EXIST'  
END
```

I need exist or not_exist to execute a flowfile or another. I tried with ResultSet(SingleRow) but I am not able.
What its the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Just change your PRINT to `SELECT 'EXIST' AS Status` and `SELECT 'NOT_EXIST' AS Status` set the result set on the execute sql task to `single row` then on the Result Set page map it your variable.  `Result Name` would be  Status and then pick your variable.

Comment: Thanks @TimMylott !! :) and can i execute one flow or another depending on the content of the variable??

Comment: @TimMylott Subqueries are not allowed in that context, you can't use PRINT with SELECT

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh you're correct, I wasn't saying use print with select.  Your answer is an option as well using an OUTPUT, both would have accomplished the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a stored with your query like below :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_testExistence]  (
@Result  varchar(10) OUTPUT ) AS

BEGIN

IF EXISTS (IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
     SELECT @Result = 'Success';
ELSE
     SELECT @Result = 'Failure';
END
```

Then create a variable named `vResult` in your SSIS package :
[image]

Then in your SQL Task, in the SQL Statement :

```
EXEC  proc_testExistence ? OUTPUT
```

Create this mapping :

[image]

Modify the Precedence Constraint for the first condition **Success** :

[image]

And for the second condition **Failure** :

[image]

Your flow is something similar to this :

[image]

You can add a [breakpoint](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-watch-value-of-variables.html) as above to check the value of your variable during debugging.